# Search and Replace Key Bindings in Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I want that when ever I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> the Sublime Text find and replace all (in selected text).

Find for (regex):

```
(\.\w+)[[:blank:]]*(\(.+),
```

replace with:

```
\1 \2,
```

how can I do so?

Comment: You can always write a plugin to achieve this if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

As @longhua said, you could write a plugin for this, for example:

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin
import re

class ReplacerCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        for region in self.view.sel():
            selected_text = self.view.substr(region)
            new_text = re.sub("(\.\w+)[[:blank:]]*(\(.+)", '\1 \2,', selected_text)
            self.view.replace(edit, region, new_text)
```

Save it in your Packages folder, and then you can add a Keybinding to run it:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+m"], "command": "replacer" }
```

Hope it helps